# Use dummy in the regression or not

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients

I have the following data:

[image]

The data shows information about prices for different kinds on different days (days are the same across the kinds). The volume shows the number of spare parts bought by the dealer for all kinds on a specific day (simply sum for all groups).

I was trying to run regression
`volume=a+b1*MB+b2*AUDI+b3*Price1+b4*Price2+b5*Price1*MB+b6*Price2*Audi...`

The coefficients b1 and b2 show different values, however, the volumes are the same for all kinds. As a result, I am thinking not to use kind dummies in this example and simply use such regression:
`volume=a+b3*Price1+b4*Price2+b5*Price1*MB+b6*Price2*Audi...`

Is it the correct way to do it as in the second example? (or even use `volume=a+b3*Price1*MB+b4*Price2*Audi+...` )

Comment: Can you please add a little more details to the question? What are you trying to predict? Overall volume for a specific date or volume for specific kind for a specific day?

Comment: As the dealer offers repair works for different kinds of the car, each of the cars has its own price for spare parts. However, the volume variable shows the sum of the spare parts bought for all kinds of cars for the specific day (AUDI+MW+MB). As a result, I want to predict overall volume (i.e. overall volume for 28.05 is 153317, but not 153317+153317+153317) at the specific date

Comment: But then for each date you basically have 9 variables: `Price1_BMW`, `Price2_BMW`, ..., `Price3_MB`, right?

Comment: Together with the response variable I mean.

Comment: Yes, for one date.

Comment: But then (as I understand the problem) you do not need the dummy variables at all, you can just use those 9 variables as predictors. Or do you alo have some other relationship in the model, apart from price-volume?

Comment: But see my dataset, it is actually with 6 variables. 9 is achieved if make my dataset wider, but the dummy logic is used to pseudo create those `Price1_BMW, Price2_BMW, ..., Price3_MB`

Comment: By "6 variables" you mean the ones that are in the table, right? You need to transfrom this dataset to run a regression anyway. So I propose the transformation such that your dataset will consist of nine independent varibles, one response variable (and date but that won't be a part of a regression)

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear to me why you are interested in running regression analysis. Thus I will try to present question you need to answer before running an analysis.

First, what is you outcome variable?
Based on you linear representation above I suspect it to be volume (or the total price).
The outcome variable is the one you seek to describe or predict based on dependent variables.

Secondly, what is you dependent variables?
Based on you text I expect it to be the kind of car, the date and the price1, 2 and 3. However it does not make much sense to me to have all prices (1,2 and3) in the regression model, since they will be a prefect predictor of the volume if they sum to the volume. (maybe I misunderstand something?)

Finally, what relation do you expect to have between your dependent variables?
Does any of them effect each other?

Based on this you can choose the type of regression analysis you want to use, and how to reshape you data suitable for the regression.

I hope it may help you further in your process